# how to implement full outer join with lucene query time join?

Tags: join, elasticsearch, solr, lucene

For the example shown [here](http://blog.trifork.com/2012/01/22/query-time-joining-in-lucene/), if i want to find all articles with all the comments present for each article, i.e. like a full outer join,how can it be done with query time join of lucene.
Is it possible that in the syntax of createJoinQuery

```
JoinUtil.createJoinQuery(fromField, multipleValuesPerDocument, toField, fromQuery, searcher);
```

fromQuery will return all the distict values for fromField?